# Rendering not getting picked from cache

Tags: jss, caching

Sitecore 9.3 - JSS

I was working on the performance aspects of my application. And I checked the details on **Stats.aspx**

[image]

The different `JsonDatRenderer` are for different Websites hosted on the instance.

1. I am unable to identify the cause that **why `From cache` was 0 for all other than the one website**.
2. And, also we are not getting data from the cache in the '**JsLayoutRenderer**'

The site settings are similar for all the websites.

Comment: Any closure on this issue you can share?